# Ajustar contenidos grandes texto a dropdown

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Tengo un menú hecho con Bootstrap 3, este cuenta con sub menús y los títulos de estos sub menús son muy grandes haciendo que el resultado final sea vea de esta forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que esos textos que en realidad los que mostrare son campos de una base de datos y lo que necesito es que se visualiza de la manera siguiente, he logrado que se vean así poniendo <br> en el texto, pero como les dijo eso texto que realmente quiere recuperar los tomare de campos de una base de datos y no quiere que el usuario final tenga que ver las etiquetas 
.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algún consejos o una solución, para solventar esto. 
Acá les dejo el código que estoy usando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
      To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a  link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and   data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown  menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of  .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To   open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link  with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-  toggle="dropdown"
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los estilos para este elemento están definidos de la siguiente forma

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a{
  ....
  white-space : nowrap // propiedad que ocasiona este detalle
}
```

Para dar una solución rápida , podría crear una nueva clase para manejar esta propiedad [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) de la siguiente forma y añadirle al elemento directamente

```
.text-wrap{
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

**Ejm**

```css
.text-wrap{
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="text-wrap">
      To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a  link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and   data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown  menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of  .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To   open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link  with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown"To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-  toggle="dropdown"
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono excelente.